# How solve a finite difference equation with integral boundary condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the problem: 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+q(x)y = f(x), 0<x<1,$$

And the boundary condition is $$\int_0^1ydx= \alpha \space \space and\space \space \int_0^1xydx= \beta$$

The question required me to do a finite difference equation with $O(h^2)$ truncation error.
Therefore, I used Centered Formula to do it, and i obtain
$$ y(x_{i+1})-(2+h^2q(x_i)+ y(x_{i-1})=f(x_i)$$

How can I show the solution in **matrix form**? (i.e. Ay=z). I can write down Ay corresponding to the L.H.S. of the above equation, but I have no idea about how to calculate the vector corresponding to $f(x_i)$. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Your centered formula is missing some symbols/terms.

Answer (score 1):

If one were to write this as a first order system for Matlabs `bvp4c` or similar, one would introduce components $(y_1,y_2)$ for $(y,y')$ and $(z_1,z_2)$ for the integrals to get the 4 differential equations
\begin{align}
y_1'(x)&=y_2(x)\\
y_2'(x)&=f(x)-q(x)y_1(x)\\
z_1'(x)&=y_1(x)\\
z_2'(x)&=xy_1(x)
\end{align}
with the 4 boundary conditions
$$
z_1(0)=z_2(0)=0,~z_1(1)=α, ~z_2(1)=β
$$

---

As you attempt a more direct discretization of second order, you can add the integrals to the system via the trapezoidal quadrature formula
$$\scriptsize
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-(2+h^2q_1)&1\\
&1&-(2+h^2q_2)&1\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&&1&-(2+h^2q_{N-2})&1\\
&&&&1&-(2+h^2q_{N-1})&1\\
\frac12&1&1&\cdots&1&1&\frac12\\
\frac12x_0&x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_{N-2}&x_{N-1}&\frac12x_N
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_0\\y_1\\y_2\\\vdots\\y_{N-2}\\y_{N-1}\\y_N
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
h^2f_1\\h^2f_2\\\vdots\\h^2f_{N-2}\\h^2f_{N-1}\\α/h\\β/h
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that you get indeed $N+1$ linear equations for the $N+1$ unknowns.

Comment: so do we need do $y_{N+1}$ ? a bit confused of the last vector showing from$f_1$to $f_{N+1}$ while the other factor just showing $f_0$  to  $f_N$ .

Comment: No, you get $N-1$ discretized PDE equations centered around $x_1,...,x_{N-1}$ and $2$ discretized integral conditions, thus $N+1$ equations for the $N+1$ variables $y_0,y_1,...,y_N$.

Comment: why isnt $x_1$ to $x_{N-1}$ for the PDE equation?

Comment: I mean like in numerical method for PDE, with general boundary condition y(0)= $/alpha$ and y(l)= $/beta$, in the matrix, we show our solution from $f_1$ to $f_N$ and for $f_0$ and $f_n$, we wont show that since they are given as our boundary point $/alpha$ and $/beta$. So in here with the changes of the boundary condition, shd we still have N PDE equation plus 2 integral condition??

Comment: It depends on the segmentation. You can construct for $N$ segments, as I did, then there are $N+1$ node points. Or you can construct for $N$ inner points, then there will be $N+2$ node points $0=x_0,x_1,...,x_N,x_{N+1}=l$.

Comment: so is that mean if i write the vector y, from $y_0$ to $y_{N+1}$, it is also ok?

Comment: Yes, if you apply the index substitution on all relevant places. It just means to replace my $N$ with a new $(N+1)$.

Comment: tks so much!! i understood that now, btw will u be able to solve the finite difference approximation of Falkner-Skan Equation? Could u plz take a look of it? 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629480/how-to-derive-a-finite-difference-approximation-of-falkner-skan-equation-with-tr